# Design SQL table (with variable columns?)

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a program that stores customer payments in a database.

It is possible to pay multiple times for one product, but I don't want to create a separate column for each payment that the customer makes.

I thought about making the number of columns variable by adding a new one after each payment, but this seems like a bad solution to me...

Any suggestions ?

I think the table should look something like this:

```
ID    ClientID   ProductID   Payment????.....
```

Comment: Think ***Rows, not Columns*** - SQL/RA works on fixed tuples/records (columns known and static) where each tuple/record can exist an arbitrary number of times in a set/relation.

Comment: Exactly. Each ROW is a transaction made by the user. The columns describes what happened in the transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments about, you should have a payment table linked to the user tables.

```
Customer
{
  ID,
  Name etc...

}

Payment
{
   Amount
   CustomerId, (foreign key to customer table)
   ProductId,
   etc...
}
```

Then to see get payments made by a Customer:

```
Select * 
From Customer 
Inner join Payment on Customer.Id = Payment.CustomerId
where customer.id == ?
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create a table that is separate for the `Payments` then you can have multiple payments for each order. Similar to this:

```
create table payments
( 
   paymentid int,
   paymentamount int,
   orderid int,
   paymentType varchar(50)
)

create table orders
(
   orderid int,
   customerid int,
)

create table customers
(
  customerid int,
  customername varchar(10)
)

create table orderdetails
(
  orderid int,
  productid int
)

create table products
(
  productid int,
  productname varchar
)
```

Setting it up in a manner like this will allow you to have multiple payments for each order.

Then you query will be:

```
select *
from customers c
left join orders o
  on c.customerid = o.customerid
left join orderdetails od
  on o.orderid = od.orderid
left join products p
  on od.productid = p.productid
left join payments ps
  on o.orderid = ps.orderid
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd think it might be necessary to keep track of each separate payment. From technical perspective it'll make your life much simpler and in transactions in real life, it might be a necessity.

Comment: Agreed, but the OP is right in that it isn't necessary (and is, in fact, bad practice) to have a separate *column* for each payment.

Comment: Definitely, I was not suggesting that (separate columns) any way.

Answer (score 0):

The typical database normalization for a product sales scenario is as follows:

```
Table: Product
(pkey) ProductID
BarCode
ProductName
Price
etc... (product description, and stuff)

Table: InvoiceItem
(pkey) InvoiceItemID
(pkey) InvoiceID
(fkey) ProductID
Quantity

Table: Invoice
(pkey) InvoiceID
*some people like InvoiceTotal here, but then you end up with multiple authorities for the total of the invoice, I prefer to derive the InvoiceTotal from the sum of InvoiceItems*

Table: Payments
(pkey) PaymentID
(fkey) InvoiceID
PaymentAmount
```

PKEY refers to the primary key for the row in the table. FKEY refers to a foreign key relationship to another entity.

In the end (when you join all this), you will end up with a vertical table that has a single Invoice with one or more Payments, with credits and depits in different columns. This allows an invoice to have multiple products on the same total and it allows multiple payments to be applied to the same invoice. As pointed out above, dynamically adding columns is going to be more confusing than anything else. Relational database design is all about a known set of columns, joining data on an unknown number of rows.